# Cinema HD Display (DVI) is not turned on is connected to Macbook pro (2013)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, cinema-display

I have a macbook pro retina 13 inchs late 2013, os x 10.9.4
I want to use a Cinema HD as external monitor.
Cinema HD uses a DVI interface.
If i connect my macbook to the monitor, Cinema HD is recognized but it is not turned on. The right resolution is identified but the led in front of the monitor is off.
You can find below a copy of the message that appears into the console when I connected the monitor to the laptop.

Any suggestions?

`29/09/14 09:27:58,000 kernel[0]: EDID CEA Extensions not valid for audio [Revision ID]: 1 (minimum value: 3)
29/09/14 09:27:59,528 WindowServer[92]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280600
29/09/14 09:27:59,529 WindowServer[92]: Found 27 modes for display 0x04280600 [27, 0]
29/09/14 09:27:59,551 WindowServer[92]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
29/09/14 09:27:59,551 WindowServer[92]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003d [1, 0]
29/09/14 09:27:59,552 WindowServer[92]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
29/09/14 09:27:59,553 WindowServer[92]: Found 35 modes for display 0x003f003e [27, 5]
29/09/14 09:27:59,553 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x003f003e changed state to online
29/09/14 09:27:59,627 WindowServer[92]: MPServiceForDisplayDevice: Invalid device alias (0)
29/09/14 09:27:59,627 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1280 x 800], 27 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0xe0ba58386be1d819c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}
29/09/14 09:27:59,628 WindowServer[92]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
29/09/14 09:27:59,628 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2304, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
29/09/14 09:27:59,628 WindowServer[92]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7fcdcad1a500) - enabling OpenGL
29/09/14 09:27:59,628 WindowServer[92]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
29/09/14 09:27:59,628 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: GL mask 0x4; bounds (1280, 0)[2560 x 1600], 35 modes available
Active, on-line, enabled, Vendor 610, Model 9223, S/N 20035d6, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0x814acfa8a4312231af5f30adf4beb549
29/09/14 09:27:59,628 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2306, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
29/09/14 09:27:59,682 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0: Mode 1280 x 800, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 2, ioModeID 0x80006000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
29/09/14 09:28:00,197 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2: Mode 1280 x 800, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 2, ioModeID 0x80006012, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
29/09/14 09:28:00,250 WindowServer[92]: hw_mirror_device_if_possible: windowserver picks master 0x4280600 as primary (driver did not pick)
29/09/14 09:28:00,258 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1280 x 800, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 2, ioModeID 0x80006000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
29/09/14 09:28:00,258 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2: Startup Mode 1280 x 800, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 2, ioModeID 0x80006012, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
29/09/14 09:28:00,258 WindowServer[92]: Display mode changed
29/09/14 09:28:00,258 WindowServer[92]: Display added
29/09/14 09:28:00,259 WindowServer[92]: Display removed
29/09/14 09:28:00,259 WindowServer[92]: Displays mirrored
29/09/14 09:28:00,260 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1280 x 800], 27 modes available
Master in mirror set; Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0xe0ba58386be1d819c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}
29/09/14 09:28:00,260 WindowServer[92]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
29/09/14 09:28:00,260 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2304, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
29/09/14 09:28:00,260 WindowServer[92]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
29/09/14 09:28:00,261 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: GL mask 0x4; bounds (0, 0)[1280 x 800], 35 modes available
Hardware mirror of 0x4280600; on-line, enabled, Vendor 610, Model 9223, S/N 20035d6, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0x814acfa8a4312231af5f30adf4beb549
29/09/14 09:28:00,261 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2305, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
29/09/14 09:28:00,286 WindowServer[92]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04280600 device: 0x7fcdcad197c0  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
29/09/14 09:28:00,302 WindowServer[92]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7fcdcad19b30) - enabling OpenGL
29/09/14 09:28:01,552 WindowServer[92]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
29/09/14 09:28:01,567 WindowServer[92]: DMPROXY (2) Found /System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
29/09/14 09:28:01,582 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:01,583 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:01,620 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:01,621 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:01,646 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:01,647 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:01,658 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:01,659 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:01,696 WindowServer[92]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
29/09/14 09:28:01,725 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:01,725 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:01,763 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:01,764 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:02,206 WindowServer[92]: DMPROXY (2) Found /System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
29/09/14 09:28:02,234 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:02,235 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:02,266 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:02,267 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:12,000 kernel[0]: The USB device Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (Port 5 of Hub at 0x14000000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (2)
29/09/14 09:28:19,000 kernel[0]: virtual bool IOHIDEventSystemUserClient::initWithTask(task_t, void *, UInt32): Client task not privileged to open IOHIDSystem for mapping memory (e00002c1)
29/09/14 09:28:19,921 System Preferences[301]: void __IOHIDEventQueueuRegister(): Unable to open IOHIDSystem (e00002bd)
29/09/14 09:28:26,719 WindowServer[92]: MPServiceForDisplayDevice: Invalid device alias (0)
29/09/14 09:28:26,719 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1280 x 800], 27 modes available
Master in mirror set; Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0xe0ba58386be1d819c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}
29/09/14 09:28:26,719 WindowServer[92]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
29/09/14 09:28:26,719 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2304, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
29/09/14 09:28:26,719 WindowServer[92]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
29/09/14 09:28:26,719 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: GL mask 0x4; bounds (0, 0)[1280 x 800], 35 modes available
Hardware mirror of 0x4280600; on-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model 9223, S/N 20035d6, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0x814acfa8a4312231af5f30adf4beb549, ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}
29/09/14 09:28:26,719 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2305, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
29/09/14 09:28:27,186 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0: Mode 1920 x 1200, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80006007, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
29/09/14 09:28:27,686 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2: Mode 1920 x 1200, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80006000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
29/09/14 09:28:27,737 WindowServer[92]: hw_mirror_device_if_possible: windowserver picks master 0x424bd16 as primary (driver did not pick)
29/09/14 09:28:27,738 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1920 x 1200, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80006007, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
29/09/14 09:28:27,738 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2: Startup Mode 1920 x 1200, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80006000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
29/09/14 09:28:27,766 WindowServer[92]: Display mode changed
29/09/14 09:28:27,766 WindowServer[92]: Displays mirrored
29/09/14 09:28:27,775 WindowServer[92]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x0424bd16 device: 0x7fcdcad19b30  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
29/09/14 09:28:27,884 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: GL mask 0x4; bounds (0, 0)[1920 x 1200], 35 modes available
Master in mirror set; Main, Active, on-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model 9223, S/N 20035d6, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0x814acfa8a4312231af5f30adf4beb549, ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}
29/09/14 09:28:27,884 WindowServer[92]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
29/09/14 09:28:27,884 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1920 x 1200], 27 modes available
Hardware mirror of 0x424bd16; on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0xe0ba58386be1d819c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}
29/09/14 09:28:27,884 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2944, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
29/09/14 09:28:27,884 WindowServer[92]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
29/09/14 09:28:27,884 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2945, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
29/09/14 09:28:29,203 WindowServer[92]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
29/09/14 09:28:29,232 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:29,233 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 3, "Cinema HD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
29/09/14 09:28:29,699 WindowServer[92]: DMPROXY (2) Found /System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
29/09/14 09:28:29,727 WindowServer[92]: Display 0x0424bd16: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 3,`

Answer (score 1):

If the cinema display unit is the 30in version, you need a converter box to change the signal out from mini-display port or thunderbolt.

This is what I use for my system, but there are others out there that will convert the signal for it.

http://www.monoprice.com/Product/?pg_no2=9&c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=6904&sortby=&period=&rating=&seq=1&format=4

I have a 2008 MBP unit, with mini-display port out, connecting to 30in Cinema Display, operating at 2560x1600 resolution with this adapter.  Requires a connection to USB port for functionality.

Regards,

Ed

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct display adapter for the Cinema HD? To the best of my knowledge, you'll need the Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter:

http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter

If you're just using the Mini DisplayPort-to-DVI adapter, that would probably explain the symptoms you're seeing.